# Combine Union All Results to One Row by Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the query below I am combining multiple queries using Union All. As you can see by the results, I am getting three rows for each date (I am assuming one row for each query), but I need to have this grouped by date on one row for each date. I have read many similar posts where `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION...` was used but I have not figured out how to make that work or if it is even what I need to use.

This is a beta query I am trying to get working. Once it is working, I will be combining 15-20 queries using this approach.

```
select 
    x.CountDate, x.ServiceDetail, x.QueueGroupEmail, x.QueueGroupChat
from
    (select convert(date, a.Date) as CountDate, count(*) as ServiceDetail, '' as QueueGroupEmail, '' as QueueGroupChat  
     from GlobalServiceDetailImport a 
     where Date >= '1/1/2024' 
     group by convert(date, a.Date)
     union all
     select convert(date, b.Date) as CountDate, '' as ServiceDetail, count(*) as QueueGroupEmail, '' as QueueGroupChat 
     from GlobalQueueGroupEmailImport b 
     where Date >= '1/1/2024' 
     group by convert(date, b.Date)
     union all
     select convert(date, c.Date) as CountDate, '' as ServiceDetail, '' as QueueGroupEmail, count(*) as QueueGroupChat 
     from GlobalChatServiceSummaryImport c 
     where Date >= '1/1/2024' 
     group by convert(date, c.Date)
    ) x
group by 
    x.CountDate, x.ServiceDetail, x.QueueGroupEmail, x.QueueGroupChat
order by 
    x.CountDate desc;
```

Results:

[image]

Required results:

[image]

Comment: There are many challenges here. First is the date strings you have are ambiguous and can be interpreted incorrectly based on collation and/or language settings. You should always use the only 100% consistent format of YYYYMMDD (no dashes or anything). Then you have columns with an empty string that will later be implicitly converted to an int. Why not use 0 instead of ''? Then in your final query just use MAX around the columns that are counted.

Comment: Aggregate and summarize your values? Now you group by on all fields which makes little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    x.CountDate, sum(x.ServiceDetail)ServiceDetail, 
    sum(x.QueueGroupEmail)QueueGroupEmail, sum(x.QueueGroupChat)QueueGroupChat
from
    (select convert(date, a.Date) as CountDate, count(*) as ServiceDetail, '' 
     as QueueGroupEmail, '' as QueueGroupChat  
     from GlobalServiceDetailImport a 
     where Date >= '1/1/2024' 
     group by convert(date, a.Date)
     union all
     select convert(date, b.Date) as CountDate, '' as ServiceDetail, count(*) 
     as QueueGroupEmail, '' as QueueGroupChat 
     from GlobalQueueGroupEmailImport b 
     where Date >= '1/1/2024' 
     group by convert(date, b.Date)
     union all
     select convert(date, c.Date) as CountDate, '' as ServiceDetail, '' as 
     QueueGroupEmail, count(*) as QueueGroupChat 
     from GlobalChatServiceSummaryImport c 
     where Date >= '1/1/2024' 
     group by convert(date, c.Date)
    ) x
group by 
    x.CountDate
order by 
    x.CountDate desc;
```

Comment: A *good* answer takes the time to **explain** the solution. It would also address other (potential) flaws in the query, such as ambiguous date formats, and bad aliasing ([Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)).

Comment: Thom, I hear you and I typically follow what is in your link. I'm just testing this code and will clean it up later. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah Thom. MNYANKEE1 use count('A') or count(any cloumn name) rather count(*). Count(*) takes more time.

Comment: in previous comment that is count(star) , don't know why it is showing as count()